# JFace Treeviewer add new root elements

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp, jface

I try to add a new element to my Treeviewer. When I add a subelement everything works fine. But I don't know how I can get the rootelement of my treeviewer to use it as parent for new root elements. I tried something like `treeviewer.add(null,element)` and `treeviwer.add(treeviwer.getTree(),element)` but nothing seems to work. Whats the best approach to add new root elements ?

Comment: `treeviewer.add(treeviewer.getInput(), element)` might work

Comment: @greg-449 Why don't you move your comment to an answer and maybe add a link to the javadoc?

Comment: Likeiwse Thank You, this was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`treeviewer.add(treeviewer.getInput(), element)` should work. The `getInput()` value is the root element of the tree.

From the `AbstractTreeViewer` comments:

> This method should be called (by the content provider) when a single
>   element has been added to the model, in order to cause the viewer to
>   accurately reflect the model. This method only affects the viewer, not
>   the model.

So be sure to update your model!